# Javascript Confirm on Form Submit Not Canceling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a pretty simple Javascript function I want to include in a form (submit or cancel). The problem is it's supposed to cancel the form submit if I push cancel. Right now it just gives me the appropriate warning, but continues with submitting the form whether I push "ok" or "cancel".

I'm new to JS so sorry if I'm missing something basic, but I can't seem to find a solid answer to this seemingly simple problem.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function confirmdelete()
{
confirm("Deleting this answer may cause dataloss, are you sure you want to continue?")
}
```

PHP / HTML

```
echo '
    <form onsubmit="confirmdelete()" class="answerform" id="deletelink" action="/admin/questions" method="post"
    onsubmit="return confirm("Do you want to delete this answer?");>
        <input type="hidden" name="ansdel" value="' . $row['id'] . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="notice" value="You have deleted: ' . $row['answer'] . '">
        <input class="answerbutton" id="deletebutton" type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by putting

```
onsubmit="return confirmdelete()"
```

Instead of

```
onsubmit="confirmdelete()"
```

That was the main issue, also used some of Rob's updates above for the final Javascript function... Thanks!

```
function confirmdelete() {
    var r=confirm("Deleting this answer may cause data loss, are you sure you want to continue?");
    if (r==true)
      {
        return true;
      }
    else
      {
        return false;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change it to

```
function confirmdelete()
{
    return confirm("Deleting this answer may cause dataloss, are you sure you want to continue?")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the confirm with an `if` statement:

```
function confirmdelete() {
    if(confirm("Deleting this answer may cause dataloss, are you sure you want to continue?")({
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also do the `return` that @mmillican recommended (much shorter, nice and simple), I just usually do the `if` statement in case you want to do some extra magic. Either one works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to assign the confirm and return it

```
var confirmed = confirm("Deleting ...
return confirmed;
```

`return false;` is what stops the form submit

Comment: * or even simpler like @mmillican's answer

Comment: No go with any of these.  If I put the "confirm("Deleting..." directly in the if statement like "if(confirm('Deleting...", the confirm doesn't pop up.  If I put the "var r=confirm(..." first and then check the if for "r" and return true or false, it still submits the form even I push cancel.  Any additional thoughts?