# Cancelling a form submission, then submitting it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a login form. What I want I am currently doing is submitting the form using action="" etc.. with an onSubmit even with my form validation inside the javascript function validate(). Currently though it will submit the form and validate at the same time. What I want to happen is for it to not submit the form, or to cancel it as soon as we get  into the validate function. And then if the forms are valid, submit the form.

This is my logic behind what I want to do

```
function validate() {
    stopFormSubmit();

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    if(username != "" && password != "") {
        submitForm();
    } else {
        displayErrors();
    }
}
```

My form looks like this

```
<form onSubmit="validate()" name="basicForm" id="basicForm" class="basicForm" action="login.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The form does validate and then submit. Validation just takes very little time.

What you really want to do is to stop the form if it fails validation.

Using intrinsic event attributes, return `false` to stop the form being submitted. Since that is determined by the success of the validation, you need to return `true` or `false` from `validate` and then return that from your event handler.

```
onSubmit="return validate()"
```

and

```
function validate() {

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    if(username != "" && password != "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        displayErrors();
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Modern code would use unobtrusive JavaScript and bind the event handlers programatically. Then it would use the Event object to control that happened to the default behaviour. Since you are already using jQuery, we can use that to perform the event binding.

Remove the `onsubmit` attribute entirely.

```
jQuery('form').on('submit', validate); // Run this after the form exists in the DOM
```

and

```
function validate(evt) {

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    if(username != "" && password != "") {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        displayErrors();
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin, if possible.

Another idea - to do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621147/javascript-confirm-on-form-submit-not-canceling?rq=1):
1. `onSubmit="return validate()"`
2. Update function:

```
function validate() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    if(username != "" && password != "") {
        submitForm();
        // or you can simply return true to allow form data submitting
    } else {
        displayErrors();
        return false;
    }
}
```